# Почему, чтобы запустить активность кликом по уведомлению используется PendingIntent?

Tags: android, android-intent

Почему я не могу просто передать `Intent(this, MainActivity.class)` в уведомление?
Не пойму почему  в `PendingIntent` должны передавать обычный `Intent`, а не напрямую в уведомление ?

Comment: Наверное дело в ограничении прав для данной ОС. Создавая Intent вы просите ОС выполнить какое-то действие. Создавая PendingIntent вы даете права кому-то выполнить действие от вашего лица.

Comment: А почему чтобы запустить активность через уведомление нужны права, это ведь уведомление этого же приложения ? Или как бы само уведомление уже не знает ничего о нашем приложении ?

Comment: Уведомления показывает стороннее приложение, которое ничего не знает о нашем (другой поток).

Comment: Понял, Спасибо.